# PROBLEMA EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

Buenas tengo que realizar varias tareas que me están volviendo loco, no sé si alguien podría ayudarme por favor.

Tengo que crear un procedimiento que inserte un alumno a mi base de datos y dos reservas a dos clases ya existentes. Este lo tengo realizado, pero la segunda parte es que tengo que realizar al menos una comprobación sobre los datos a insertar utilizando funciones de librería, si los datos a insertar no cumplen la condición, no realizara la inserción y se mostrara un mensaje.

El código el procedimiento es el siguiente;

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE NuevoAlumnoReserva
(IN Id_Alumno VARCHAR(10),
IN Nombre VARCHAR(15),
IN Apellido VARCHAR(25),
IN DNI VARCHAR(15),
IN Id_Clase1 VARCHAR(10), 
IN FechaMatricula1 DATE,
IN Id_Clase2 VARCHAR(10), 
IN FechaMatricula2 DATE)
BEGIN
#Inserccion de alumno nuevo
INSERT INTO
ALUMNO (Id_Alumno,Nombre,Apellido,DNI)
VALUES
(Id_Alumno,Nombre,Apellido,DNI);
#reserva de la primera clase
INSERT INTO
MATRICULA (Id_Alumno,Id_Clase,FechaMatricula)
VALUES
(Id_Alumno,Id_Clase1,FechaMatricula1);
#reserva de la segunda clase
INSERT INTO
MATRICULA (Id_Alumno,Id_Clase,FechaMatricula)
VALUES
(Id_Alumno,Id_Clase2,FechaMatricula2);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Gracias por la ayuda que me podáis aportar llevo días con esto y no me sale.

Comment: Por favor, aporta el dataset con algunos registros de ejemplo. Así como las comprobaciones a realizar, aunque sean funciones vacías.

Comment: Buenas esta es mi base de datos y los datos introducidos.

Comment: Buenas David la verdad es que esto es lo que tengo, no se si te servira soy altruista y no se muy bien lo que me pides.ALUMNO(Id_Alumno, Nombre, Apellido, DNI)
  MATRICULA(Id_Alumno, Id_Clase, FechaMatricula)
  PROFESOR(Id_Profe, Nombre, Teléf, Especialidad)
  CLASE(Id_Clase, Materia, Aula, Participantes, Id_Profe)
  DIRECTOR(Id_Profe, Id_Director)
  RESERVA(Id_Alumno, Id_Espac, FechaEntrada)
  ESPACIOMEDITACION(Id_Espac, Tipo)
  BONO(Id_Bono,Fechacompra, Tarjeta, Efectivo, Id_Alumno)
  NºCLAS( Id_Bono , NºClases)
  TEMPMAXI( Id_Bono, Duración)

Comment: ¿Es posible que nos dejes la estructura con algunos registros de ejemplo en formado SQL? Desde phpMyAdmin, opción Exportar. Mejor modifica la pregunta, que en los comentarios no hay espacio suficiente